# Which Recycler Adapter method is called when recycler wants to recycler an adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am aware that a `recycler` adapter and `listview` basically `recycles` adapters that can fit a given screen giving the user the `illusion` of multiple items, my main reason for this question is because I have an app that loads a great deal of images in a `recycler` using `Picasso` but I noticed Picasso is not doing the job as expected, my app uses roughly `10mb` on the `emulator` and about `4mb` on real devices, this is really good for an app that displays images but I want to go further, I want to be recycling bitmaps myself in the method that is called when an adapter leaves the screen, that is, since views are recycled there has to be a method that removes data out of an adapter and refills it with new data to make that  `illusion` a reality, I looked at the recycler adapter documentation and I noted 2 methods the `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow` both of which cannot be overridden, anyone have an idea on how I can approach my problem?

Answer (score 3):

solved it, I had to override `onViewRecycled` and the previous 2 methods are overridenable except I did not know how to, I know do.

```
   @Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    //destory anything here


}
```

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet of what you did inside this method?